# How to disable Google Chrome request to install website app?

Tags: chrome-for-android, google

This message is quite new. I get it when I visit reddit.com but also developer.android.com and other sites.

It only comes once so when you visit one of the sites I named perhaps you won't see this message.

It is not simply an HTML message because you can see it overlaps the address bar.

When I clicked *install* it installed an app which cannot be found on the Play Store.

How to disable this message for all sites?

[image: screenshot]